# How can I switch fire mode in Call of Duty Modern Warfare Remastered?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

I've tried several weapons with <kbd>B</kbd>, and nothing happens

Comment: Have you checked your keybinds? What does it have for fire mode switch?

Comment: I checked control settings, it has no option for that in there..

Answer (score 2):

The default button is <kbd>B</kbd>.

---

> **Gaining Complete Control**
>
> When using a keyboard and mouse in Modern Warfare on default settings, these are the keybinds that have the following basic commands (these commands can be all be re-bound to keys within the Settings menu):
>
> **...**
>
> B – Alternate Fire: Utilizing this function when using a weapon that offers multiple firing modes – i.e. an Assault Rifle that has both fully-automatic and burst fire modes – changes the fire mode of that weapon.
>
> **[- "GETTING STARTED IN MODERN WARFARE®: CONTROLS AND SETTINGS (PC)" @ blog.activision.com](https://blog.activision.com/call-of-duty/2019-10/Getting-Started-in-Modern-Warfare-Controls-and-Settings-PC)**

---

As others have said, if <kbd>B</kbd> does not work, I would double check key bindings.

Failing that, I would make sure the weapon actually has alternate firing modes.

Failing that, I would double check your <kbd>B</kbd> button works; I suspect it must if you successfully used the character in the question.

Failing that, I would reach out to [the Activision technical support team](https://support.activision.com/au/en/modern-warfare).